# Property is not associated to model if relation using "as"

Tags: sequelize.js

Database: mysql 5.5

Sequelize version: 3.30.4

User role model

```
sequelize.define('userRole', {
    uid: {
      type: DataTypes.UUID,
      primaryKey: true
    },
    name: {
      type: DataTypes.STRING,
      unique: true
    }
  },
    {
      freezeTableName: false,
      tableName: 'user_roles'
    }
  )
```

User model

```
sequelize.define('user', {
    uid: {
      type: DataTypes.UUID,
      primaryKey: true
    },
    login: {
      type: DataTypes.STRING,
      unique: true,
      allowNull: false
    }
  },
    {
      freezeTableName: false,
      tableName: 'users'
    }
  )
```

And relation

```
Users.belongsTo(UserRoles, { as: 'role' })
```

Trying to insert new user

```
Users.create({
    uid: uuid(),
    login: 'login',
    password: 'password',
    role: {
      uid: uuid(),
      name: 'admin'
    }
  }, {
      include: [Types.UserRoles]
    })
```

> Error: userRole is not associated to user!

Tried to use

```
role: {
      uid: uuid(),
      name: 'admin'
    }
```

or

```
userRole: {
      uid: uuid(),
      name: 'admin'
    }
```

but no difference

If i change relation to

```
Users.belongsTo(UserRoles)
```

all is fine

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When defining relation with `as` option, you need to remember to include the alias when performing query with eager loading of those relations, so you need to change your `create()` and add the `as` option in `include`:

```js
Users.create({
    uid: uuid(),
    login: 'login',
    password: 'password',
    role: {
      uid: uuid(),
      name: 'admin'
    }
  }, {
      include: [{ model: Types.UserRoles, as: 'role' }]
});
```

Answer (score 1):

If you use `sequelize.sync()` in your code than to table `Users` will add column `UserRolesId`

If you don't use `sequelize.sync()` then you need add field 'roleId' to table `users' and then  describe relation like

```js
Users.belongsTo(UserRoles, {
  foreignKey: 'roleId',
  constraints: false, //is's optional
  as: 'post'
});
```

read extra example - http://docs.sequelizejs.com/en/latest/docs/associations/

Comment: Thanks, but my question not about this